# Как в миграции очистить таблицу в laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, миграция

Или очистить определённый столбец

Comment: Миграции - это не средство манипуляции данными, миграции - это средство манипуляции структурой данных. Наверняка технически это осуществимо, но вы не должны этим заниматься в миграциях.

Comment: Ну допустим приложение ещё не запущено, но в нём какие то тестовые данные, а мне надо уменьшить длину строки. Выполнится ли такая миграция, если у меня там есть строки длиннее чем новое значение?

Comment: @Etki не согласна, а если нужно обновить данные как раз в связи с изменением структуры (например тип колонки поменялся). Тогда как раз лучше чтобы все вместе прогонялось и откатывалось

Comment: @apelsinka223 как вы поменяете тип данных без изменения типа колонки?

Comment: @Etki например добавлю копию колонки, переложу данные с изменениями, удалю первую колонку и переименую копию. Или если не нужно сохранять данные то просто удалю все

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается с помощью **statement** запроса.

`DB::statement('truncate table users');`

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте обычный sql запрос внутри миграции
`TRUNCATE TABLE Table` или `UPDATE Table SET column = NULL`